# User login to be shared from JSF to non-JSF page

Tags: spring, jsf

I have a Spring Java web application with JSF for frontend. To this app, I am trying to add another module, but the new module is developed using Angular and I don't plan to use JSF for future modules as well. The only problem being faced is the login which takes place through old JSF pages, cannot be directly accessed in the same session for the new module. So the scenario is, user logs in on the url:

server:8080/faces/pages/login.xhtml

and then visits new URL for new module at

server:8080/pages/newmod.html

My impression was that the browser session for the application remains the same, so it should be possible to access the faces session object in the new controller like this:

```
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userSession");
```

But as expected, this is returning null, causing further null pointer exceptions in the code. I think it wont be possible to directly use FacesContext in the new controller, but do not know how exactly this can be achieved. Can anyone please suggest a solution to share user login from faces page to a non-jsf part of the code?

Comment: Well obviously you cannot access faces outside of faces that isn't going to work. The `userSession` should be a regular session attribute which you can retrieve `session.getAttribute("userSession")`. Or use `WebUtils.getRequiredSessionAttribute("userSession", session)`.

Comment: Are you saying that `get("userSession")` returned `null`, or that `getCurrentInstance()` returned `null`?

Comment: @ BalusC I am not exactly sure, but I assigned the returning object to a userSessionBean and assigned userID from this bean to a local variable. The null pointer exception occurred in my DAO class where the useID was passed.  Exception did not occur at the controller where userSessionBean is being created, but I think its either returning a null object for userSessionBean or the userSessionBean does not have the expected userID. [ P.S. I am new to faces, and taking over from old developers, so please excuse if it sounds little stupid.]

Comment: @M.Deinum session.getAttribute() method worked very well. Thanks a lot. Here is the exact code: `public void fooFunction(HttpSession session) {
  UserSessionBean userSessionBean = (UserSessionBean) session.getAttribute("userSession");
  if (userSessionBean != null) {
            this.customerId = userSessionBean.getUserId();
        }`